# Receive updates from UIApplication.shared object in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this function that checks if a given app is installed on the device:

```
import UIKit

func isAppInstalled(appName: String) -> Bool {
    let appScheme = "\(appName)://"
    guard let appUrl = URL(string: appScheme) else {
        return false
    }
    
    return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appUrl)
}
```

How do I reload a SwiftUI View that uses that value when that value changes?

Comment: Why would you need to? What is it that _calls_ that method?

Comment: @matt if the app is installed then I show a Text with "Installed", otherwise "Not installed". The thing is that users expect the view to update when they delete a certain app, right when they come back.

Comment: So register to hear when we “come back”. Wrap your function in an observable object and use a value that it publishes.

Comment: Thank you. Could it be one way to use `sceneDidBecomeActive`?

Comment: Yes but use the notification, not the delegate. In iOS 14 there is no delegate.